# nodejs elementtree npm xml parsing and merging

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, parsing, elementtree

I have a question on same module as I posted last time in below post. Seems like, it is quite difficult to deal with XML parsing. With elementTree having very mearge documentation.

I have a below template_XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Tailoring xmlns="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.2" id="xccdf_org.open-scap_tailoring_example">
<status>incomplete</status>
<version time="2013-01-15T16:00:00.000+02:00">1.0</version>
    <Profile id="PlaceHolder">
    <title>Tailoring for py_test</title>
    <select idref="xccdf_rule_name" selected="true"/>
</Profile>
</Tailoring>
```

And a below sample_XML file:

```
<Benchmark xmlns="http://checklists.nist.gov/xccdf/1.1" xmlns:xsi="www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="SAP-HANA" resolved="1" xml:lang="en-US">
<status date="2016-03-17">draft</status>
<title xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">Guide to the Secure Configuration of SAP HANA</title>
<version>0.1.28</version>

<Profile id="profile1">
    <title xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">text1</title>
    <select idref="This is rule 1" selected="true"/>
    <set-value idref="ssfs_master_key_timeout">20</set-value>
</Profile> 

<Profile id="profile2">
    <title xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-US">text2</title>
    <select idref="this is rule1" selected="true"/>
    <select idref="this is rule1" selected="true"/>
    <select idref="this is rule1" selected="true"/>
</Profile>
</Benchmark>
```

I need to create a **new_xml** file, a **copy of** template_XML file.
But want to replace "**PlaceHolder**" profile tag in **new_xml** file with the "**profile2**" tag of **sample_XML** file. Its a kind of merging of 2 xml file and creating a new one.
Below is the code I have tried:

```
function call(id){
    var template_XML = 'C:\\MyDrive\\template_XML';
    var new_xml = 'C:\\MyDrive\\new_xml';
    data = fs.readFileSync(template_XML).toString();
    data1 = fs.readFileSync(sample_XML).toString();
    etree = et.parse(data);
    etree1 = et.parse(data1);
    var profile = etree.find('./Profile');  // Getting the profile sub-element.
    etree.getroot().remove(profile)         // Removing the sub-element. So that I can insert new profile from sample file

    var profiles = etree1.findall('./Profile'); // Find the required profile.
    for (var i = 0; i < profiles.length; i++) {
        if(profiles[i].get('id') == 'profile2')
            var tmppro = profiles[i];
    }
    console.log(tmppro);
    etree.insert(3,tmppro);     // insert it. Failing

    var write = fs.openSync(new_xml, 'w');
    etree.write(write);                     // write it. Failing
}
```

For one or the other reason, this code is not working in terms of "etree.insert" and "etree.write"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I was able to make it working with current lib.
Please see my comments:

```js
'use strict';

const et = require('elementtree');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

function populateXmlTemplate(id) {
 //Please use path.join to make it cross-platform
 var template_XML = path.join(__dirname, 'template.xml');
 var sample_XML = path.join(__dirname, 'sample.xml');
 var new_xml = path.join(__dirname, 'new.xml');

 var data = fs.readFileSync(template_XML).toString();
 var data1 = fs.readFileSync(sample_XML).toString();

 var etree = et.parse(data);
 var etree1 = et.parse(data1);

 var root = etree.getroot();

 var placeholder = root.find('./Profile');
 root.remove(placeholder);

 var profiles = etree1.findall('./Profile'); // Find the required profile.
 for (var i = 0; i < profiles.length; i++) {
  //If I get it right, it shouldn't be hardcoded
  if (profiles[i].get('id') == id) {
   var tmppro = profiles[i];
  }
 }

 //After you removed the placeholder the number of children decreased
 //So it should be 2, not 3.
 //Also etree doesn't have insert method, please call root.insert
 root.insert(2, tmppro);

 //You have been writing the document a bit incorrectly.
 var resultXml = etree.write();
 fs.writeFileSync(new_xml, resultXml);
}

populateXmlTemplate('profile2');

module.exports = {populateXmlTemplate};
```

But you're right, the documentation is not good. It's mostly missing. So mostly I simply have been [debugging](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2016.3/running-and-debugging-node-js.html#debugLocal) it to see the available methods, also there are some [tests](https://github.com/racker/node-elementtree/tree/master/tests) in the lib repo.

There are other modules to work with js. Please see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14890740/7006062).

Comment: Thanks a ton Antonio, WebStorm will help me a lot in writing further application. In fact I was not aware of any IDE for nodejs application.
populateXmlTemplate() is throwing below stack trace, but now its OK, I will handle the situation by debugging it in IDE.
etree.write(); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'iter' of undefined

It seems I need +15reputation to upvote an answer, however my upvote is noted. :)

Comment: Hi Antonio, any idea if I can copy the comment also. For example if <Profile> tag contains comments <!-- SOME COMMENT -->.

ETREE is not copying the comments section from sample_XML profile into the new_xml file.