# how to read two different xml files and append a new xml file in javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, append

I generated two different xml file in javascript

First:

```
writeFile('licenses/licenses.xml', xml , function(err) {
        if (err) console.log(err);
    });
```

Second:

```
writeFile('./licenses/NuGetLicenses.xml', result , function(err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

How to append these files (format must be xml) in javascript. I saw same topics question but I didn't find any solution. I need help.

Comment: This is node.js I assume?

Comment: For example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553153/nodejs-elementtree-npm-xml-parsing-and-merging